# Where can i find platform android-14 in my computer?

Tags: android

I'm used to find all SDK resources (such as images, that is what I want) in folder `android-sdk>platforms>android-[VERSION_NUMBER]>data>res` but I can't find the new android-14 folder.

[image]

I've updated all 4.0 tools (as you can see in the image) and the API 14 emulator works

[image]

I tried downloading the SDK folder from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), but it doesn't contain images. How can I access Android 4.0 resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried searching for a folder with the name `android-14`? I'm thinking the SDK Updater might have placed it elsewhere - all though I don't know why it would have done it.

Since you have the tools installed - the folder should be there. (I have one at least).

Comment: +1 for you. Thanks for the suggestion, I don't know why but it's in `C:\Android\platforms\.."